# can't find osgearth cache utility

Tags: osgearth

I want to revive one of my old projects. The old environment was VS2010 and I want to upgrade it to VS2015. In VS2010 I used to cache image and elevation data with osgearth_cache.exe (I don't remember where it's came from). It was very useful tool for offline setup configuration. The problem that now all my attempts to find this utility in new osgearth github packages was in vain, it just not there. Any ideas ? what Im missing ?

Answer (score 0):

`osgearth_package` can be used to download map data for later offline use.

It can be found in `src/applications/osgearth_package`

This is a better solution than using `osgearth_cache` in my experience.

`osgearth_cache` can be found in `src/applications/osgearth_seed`

This is based on osgearth 2.10. Latest 3.0 I believe also has these tools.